# Android camera works for one time only after giving permission

Tags: java, android, camera, arcore

I try to show the content of the built-in camera inside my android device using ArCore. I have handled a code for asking permission at the beginning of the application. If I provide the permission I can see the current image stream coming from the camera.

After relaunching the application the result is black. The only solution is to revoke the camera permission inside the setting. Then the application asks again for permission and shows the image stream on the screen.

Is anybody who face the same problem? Do I have to refresh the permission? If I do `RequestCameraPermission();` without checking permission, the activity is paused and resumed in a cycle. But I can see the first frame.

In the console the following error appears:

`D/ACameraDevice: Device error received, code 3, frame number 51, request ID 0, subseq ID 0`
and `android_camera.cc:1088 Camera capture failed! frame: 51 reason: 1`.

Code 3 is `ERROR_CAMERA_DISABLED` depending on https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_development/blob/master/ndk/platforms/android-24/include/camera/NdkCameraDevice.h

After some time only

`I/native: analytics_logger.cc:190 The AnalyticsClient.sendAnalyticsMessage() method returned false. Will retry...`

```
E/native: analytics_logger.cc:198 Could not send event. Event will be dropped.
```

is called in a loop. There is no activity anymore.

My code:

```
public class GameActivity extends NativeActivity
{
  static GameActivity s_Instance;

  public static GameActivity GetInstance()
  {
      return s_Instance;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle _SavedInstanceState)
  {
      super.onCreate(_SavedInstanceState);

      s_Instance = this;

      nativeInitializeInterface(getApplicationContext());
  }

  @Override
  public void onStart() {
      super.onStart();
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume()
  {
      super.onResume();

      if (!HasCameraPermission())
      {
          RequestCameraPermission();

          return;
      }

      RequestCameraPermission();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause()
  {
      super.onPause();
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop()
  {
      super.onStop();
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy()
  {
      super.onDestroy();
  }

  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int _RequestCode, String[] _Permissions, int[] _Results)
  {
      if (!HasCameraPermission())
      {
          Toast.makeText(this, "Camera permission is needed to run this application", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          if (!ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale())
          {
              // Permission denied with checking "Do not ask again".
              LaunchPermissionSettings();
          }

          finish();
      }
  }

  public int GetDeviceOrientation()
  {
      return getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
  }

  public int GetDeviceRotation()
  {
      return getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
  }

  public int GetDeviceDimensionWidth()
  {
      Point Size = new Point();

      getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(Size);

      return Size.x;
  }

  public int GetDeviceDimensionHeight()
  {
      Point Size = new Point();

      getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(Size);

      return Size.y;
  }

  public boolean HasCameraPermission()
  {
      return this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
  }


  public void RequestCameraPermission()
  {
      this.requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 0);
  }

  public boolean ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()
  {
      return this.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
  }

  public void LaunchPermissionSettings()
  {
      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
      intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("package", this.getPackageName(), null));

      this.startActivity(intent);
  }

  public native void nativeInitializeInterface(Context context);

  static
  {
      System.loadLibrary("app_droid");
  }
}
```

Comment: Put your entire activity code for better understanding and quick solution

Comment: If it will help!

Comment: Are you using "nativeInitializeInterface" method to show camera with data?

Comment: No. Just for sending the context to the ArSession.

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly do you have the logic for presenting the image on screen? Maybe you only have it inside the permission granted callback.

(I'd put this answer as a comment, but can't yet due to reputation)

Comment: I render the image on the screen via my graphics engine written in C++. I have used a GameActivity derived from NativeActivity. The game activity is started using the provided native_app_glue library/example.